# Disabling mouse in Vim disables indentation

Tags: vim, freebsd, mouse, indentation

I have Vim version 8.0.122 on FreeBSD 9.3 (installed with pkg). I have default global vimrc. I want to disable mouse support completely on my account, so I put

```
    set mouse=
```

in my local .vimrc. It works, mouse is disabled, but also autoindent is gone, i.e. I press enter in a .php or .c file and I'm back at the begining of the line instead of current indent position.

I want to have both, mouse disabled, autoindent working as it used to. What should I do?

Comment: Please add to the post how you disabled it.

Comment: They are not linked in any way. To debug, make a simple `.vimrc` file containing just `set nocompatible`, `set all&`, `set ai bs=2 mouse=` and check that everything works correctly. Then try to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem. This is what helped me solve it.
On my computer the vim settings which made many things pretty are stored in `/usr/shar/vim/vim*/defaults.vim`, but this file was read only if there is no `~/.vimrc`. So if you can either copy this entire file to you `~/.vimrc`, or if you are an admin and want to make a change for all users, modify the file itself. Just comment out the line which says `set mouse=a`.